# How to send a HTTP Request with an OAuth 2.0 Access Token using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I wanted to send an Http Request with an `OAuth2 Access Token` to an API.

I have used this code for sending `Bearer Token`.

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
         {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://someurl"),
            Headers = {
                { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
                { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json"},
                { "client-id", "clientid"},
                { "client-secret","clientsecret"},
                { "partner-id","partnerid"},
                { "X-Version", "1" }
                },
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fileJson))
                    };

 var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

This is working when sending `Bearer Token` but doesn't work when sending an `Oauth2 Access Token`. I wanted to send the `Oauth2 Access Token` to the API. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: To send an OAuth 2 Access Token you use the 'Bearer' type just like your first example. `Authorization: Bearer <replace_with_oauth_token>`

Comment: But when i used this code to send an access token it's response is this `StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1`

Comment: 500 error means Internal Server Error trying to process your request. This is a general error but means that your request has a serious problem (the server code probably crashed) or a poorly written server. If the error was in the 400s then this would be a permission related issue. Read the API documentation and debug. what server/service are you calling? Remember in software development, it is the details that matter.

Comment: @John Hanley Thanks for this :)